# Find function whose power series representation is $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} k x^k$ for $|x|<1$

Tags: functional-analysis, power-series

Please check my work:

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k $$

for $|x|<1$ is the geometric series, which we know converges uniformly

Then by either differentiation or multiplication we see that

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + ... = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k x^{k-1}$$

We check that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k x^{k-1}$ converges with the Ratio Test

$$\lim_{k\to \infty} \left\lvert \frac{(k+1) x^k}{k x^{k-1}} \right\rvert =\lim_{k\to \infty} \left\lvert \frac{(k+1) x}{k} \right\rvert \le \lim_{k\to \infty} \left\lvert \frac{(k+1)}{k} \right\rvert \left\lvert x \right\rvert$$

$$\lim_{k\to \infty} \left\lvert \frac{(k+1)}{k} \right\rvert \left\lvert x \right\rvert = |x| <1 $$

So $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k x^{k-1}$ converges and since it is a Power Series in its interval of convergence, it converges absolutely and hence uniformly by the Weierstrauss M-test

Now since $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k x^{k-1}$ converges uniformly and the geometric series converges uniformly, it follows that

$$ \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} - \frac{1}{1-x}*\frac{1-x}{1-x} = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k x^{k-1} - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kx^k $$

This proves that the function we are looking for is:

$$ \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} $$

Comment: Everything looks okay.

Comment: Note that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{k}$ converges absolutely for $|x| < 1$, therefore $(\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{k})^2 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^nx^k$ converges absolutely and we can change the order of summation : $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+k} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n+k= m} x^{n+k} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty x^m (m+1)$, proving that it converges absolutely for $|x| < 1$

Comment: You should make sure to be consistent with your exponent variable and your summation index. As it currently stands, the summation $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^k$ does not equal $\frac{1}{1-x}$. In fact, $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^k$ is not finite.

Comment: @GrancescoFrechi good catch. The script I was bumming off of had $i $ I forgot to change them

Comment: @user1952009 thanks for pointing that out, for multiplication.  I'm working from Rudin so assuming I differentiated to that form, then Theorem 8.1 of his book already guarantees the existence of this derivative so I would have no need to take the extra step.  But I didn't specify